# conn.flush() will not flush all record to redis

Tags: go, redigo

this is code

```
 func main() {
   ...
   pool := createPool(*redis_server, *redis_pass)
   defer pool.Close()
   c := pool.Get() 
   var i int64
   st := tickSec()
   for i = 0; i < *total; i++ {
      r := time.Now().Unix() - rand.Int63n(60*60*24*31*12)
      score, _ := strconv.Atoi(time.Unix(r, 0).Format("2006010215"))
      id := utee.PlainMd5(uuid.NewUUID().String())
      c.Send("ZADD", "app_a_5512", score, id)
      if i%10000 == 0 {
          c.Flush()
          log.Println("current sync to redis", i)
      }
  }
  //c.Flush()
  c.Close()
  ...
}
```

if i use c.Close(),the total set 100000,the real sortedset count 100000.
but if i use c.Flush(),the total also set 100000, the real sortedset count less than 100000(96932);if i use time.Sleep() in the end of the main func,the total is 100000 too.

when main func exit,the flush func is not complete?and why? thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that the program works when Close() is called after the loop is that the pooled connection's Close() method reads and discards all pending responses.

The application should [Receive](https://godoc.org/github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis#Conn.Receive) the responses for all commands instead of letting the respones backup and consume memory on the server. There's no need to flush in the loop.

```
go func() {
  for i = 0; i < *total; i++ {
     r := time.Now().Unix() - rand.Int63n(60*60*24*31*12)
     score, _ := strconv.Atoi(time.Unix(r, 0).Format("2006010215"))
     id := utee.PlainMd5(uuid.NewUUID().String())
     c.Send("ZADD", "app_a_5512", score, id)
  }
  c.Flush()
}

for i = 0; i < *total; i++ {
   c.Receive()
}
c.Close()
```

Also, the application should check and handle the errors returns from Send, Flush and Receive.

Comment: the Close() will discard all pending responses.but the flush won't?               i use flush int the loop because the total is very large and it consume a large amount of memory.thank you!

Comment: Flush writes the data to the network. Flush does not read responses.  The pooled connecton's Close method attempts to return the connection to a "neutral" state before returning the underlying connection to the pool.  This includes flushing any commands written by the application and reading all responses that the application has not yet read.

Comment: The connection buffers data using a [bufio.Writer](https://godoc.org/bufio#Writer).  A bufio.Writer uses a fixed size buffer.